# Serving Node.JS app on a existing server running page on port 80

Tags: node.js, apache

I have a server at www.example.com running a PHP-made webpage served by Apache, this page is listening to port 80.

Now I want to serve my Node.JS on the domain www.example2.com. Both pages should be on the same server, the Node.JS app should be running on port 3000. **How do I achieve this?**

From other answers and blog posts (like this one: http://garr.me/blog/running-node-js-and-apache-together-using-mod_proxy/) I have learnt that I can create a ReverseProxy to redirect www.example.com/app to my app, however this is not the intended behavior. What I want is this new domain www.example2.com to go the server's ip address at port 3000.

*Side question: This question might sound stupid but, can't I redirect the whole domain to the server's IP address at port 3000 from the domain name configuration at GoDaddy/Route53???*

Thanks.

Comment: Try digging in [ServerFault: search for node.js apache is:question answers:1..](http://serverfault.com/search?tab=relevance&q=node.js%20apache%20is%3aquestion%20answers%3a1..)

Answer (score 0):

Yes to your side question. i think thats the best approach. Have your domain configuation on go daddy go to the ip address and 3000 port.